# Bind function only to clicked link without using an id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using data attributes on my anchor tags but when the following event is fired it changes all links with that attribute, *obviously* I guess. I don't want to use ids I just want to bind the event only to the clicked link...should be super easy but I can't solve this. **This is being used in conjunction with Twitter Bootstrap collapse** for a read more / read less excerpt function.

```
//Excerpt functions
$('.collapse').on('shown', function () {
  $('[data-target]').click(function() {
    $(this).html('&raquo More');
  });
});
$('.collapse').on('hidden', function () {
  $('[data-target]').click(function() {
    $(this).html('&laquo Less');
  });
});
```

my html looks like this

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more1">&raquo; More</a>
<div id="more1" class="collapse"></div>
```

Comment: What does the html look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).find('[data-target]').click(...` instead.

After checking your html posted in the comment, you should do:

```
$(this).prev('[data-target]').click(...
```

Comment: Assuming that collapse has an element inside it with a data-attribute defined, this is the correct answer. +1.

Comment: I tried `$('.collapse').on('shown', function () {
             $(this).find('[data-target]').click(function() {
               $(this).html('&raquo More');
           });
         });
     $('.collapse').on('hidden', function () {
        $(this).find('[data-target]').click(function() {
          $(this).html('&laquo Less');
        });
      });`
But no luck...?

Comment: None of the above worked for me. This example below works but you have to click a link twice. Then it works everywhere on the page. But I'm still faced with it propagating to all other data-target attributes...?



`//Excerpt functions
$('.collapse').on('shown', function () {
    $('[data-target]').click(function() {
      $(this).html('&raquo More');
  });
});
$('.collapse').on('hidden', function () {
    $('[data-target]').click(function() {
      $(this).html('&laquo Less');
  });
});`